# Падение производительности после использования setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

Tags: c++, кодировка, winapi

Написал небольшую программу, парсящую файлы и папки в указанной директории и вытаскивающую их аттрибуты с помощью WinAPI (FindFirstFile, FindNextFile). Все хорошо, стал тестировать на 1к файлов в директории - парсилось и выводилось в консоль меньше, чем за секунду. Возникла проблема при указании пути кириллицей. Воспользовался setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus") после чего парсинг этой же папки стал проходить за 8 секунд.

Есть ли решения проблемы производительности в данном случае, ибо она критична?

В проекте использую Multi-Byte Character Set. Windows 7 64x. Visual Studio 15. Портироваться на другие платформы приложение не будет. Использование Qt и прочих фреймворков невозможно.

Comment: Какое-то профилирование кода производилось чтобы понять, где конкретно проседает производительность?

Comment: во время цикла
do
{
       \\ blablabla
} while (FindNextFile(handle, &p) != 0);

Comment: Т.е. просто на глаз, что `\\ blablabla` стало реже проявляться? Я имел в виду более серьёзные инструменты.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Написал реализацию по вашему описанию. Работает без тормозов.

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    int iscreate = 0;

    if(iscreate){
        mkdir("тест");
        chdir("тест");

        for(int i = 0; i < 1024; i ++){
            char buf[1024];

            HFILE fl = open(itoa(i, buf, 10), O_CREAT, S_IREAD|S_IWRITE);
            close(fl);
        }

        return 0;
    }

    HANDLE find_handle;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA ff;

    find_handle = FindFirstFile("тест/*.*", &ff);
    if(find_handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return 0;

    while(1){
        printf("File: %s\r\n", ff.cFileName);

        if(!FindNextFile(find_handle, &ff))
            break;      
    }

    FindClose(find_handle);


    return 0;
```

Будет ли мой пример работать с такой же задержкой?

В 15 студии наверняка есть профилировщик, научитесь им пользоваться.

Или можете воспользоваться моими дефайнами для измерения времени:

```
#define tbtime timeb ft, fte; int tbtime_sec, tbtime_millim, tbtime_result; ftime(&ft); // print("Time: ", itos(sec*1000+millitm), "ms.\r\n");
#define tctime ftime(&ft); // continue
#define tetime ftime(&fte); tbtime_sec=fte.time-ft.time; tbtime_millim=fte.millitm-ft.millitm; if(fte.millitm<ft.millitm){ tbtime_millim+=1000; tbtime_sec--; } tbtime_result = tbtime_sec * 1000 + tbtime_millim;
```

tbtime запускать в начале программы для инициализации переменных. tctime для начала нового отсчета времени. tetime для получения количества мс. прошедших с начала отсчета, результат будет в tbtime_result в милисекундах.

Короче, ищите где именно у вас тормозит.